# How can I require a confirmed email or phone for sign in?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a system which will allow users to register with their email or phone number as the username. We want to confirm this is valid before allowing login. We're using ASP.NET Core Identity with Identity Server 4.

I've found instructions to require a confirmed phone, and to require a confirmed email (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sign-in), but I can't find how to use them as an OR option for confirmed email or phone.

There is a `RequireConfirmedAccount` property, but this seems to only check the email and fails if only the phone number is confirmed.

Is there a way for me to override this, or inject my own login manager to enforce this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found that we can provide a custom SignInManager and override the CanSignInAsync method, based on the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/4303bbe78650abf0bc6941d81956b02e4357feb5/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L143):

```
public class CustomSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    // ..default constructor

    public override async Task<bool> CanSignInAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var emailConfirmed = await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user);
        var phoneConfirmed = await UserManager.IsPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user);
        
        return emailConfirmed || phoneConfirmed;

    }
}
```

Then in `startup.cs`, add a custom SignInManager in the Identity config:

```
                services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
                {
                    ...
                })
                .AddSignInManager<CustomSignInManager>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```